# React how to properly call a component function inside render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a sidebar menu skeleton using **ReactJs** and need to understand the way to call a function inside **ReactJs** `render()` function.

The code is below:

```
import React from 'react';

var menuData = require("./data/admin.menu.json");

class SidebarMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { expanded: true };
    this.buildItem = this.buildItem.bind(this);
  };

  buildItem(title, ref, icon) {
    return (
      <div className={"item" + this.props.key}>
        <a href={ref}>{title}<i className={"fa " + icon} /></a>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {
          menuData.forEach(function (item) {
            this.buildItem(item.title, item.ref, item.icon);

            if (item.hasOwnProperty("submenu")) {
              item.submenu.forEach(function (subitem) {
                this.buildItem(subitem.title, subitem.ref, subitem.icon);
              });
            }
          })
        }

      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default SidebarMenu;
```

The given code shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buildItem' of undefined
```

How to properly call a function that will render data inside the **ReactJs** function ?

Comment: please next time format your code before posting! takes exactly 2 seconds and makes it so much easier to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is one solution, using fat arrow, AKA arrow functions:

```
import React from 'react';

var menuData = require("./data/admin.menu.json");

class SidebarMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = { expanded: true };

      this.buildItem = this.buildItem.bind(this);
  };

  buildItem(title, ref, icon) {

    return (
      <div className={"item" + this.props.key}>
        <a href={ref}>{title}<i className={"fa " + item.icon}/></a>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {

      return (
        <div>
          {
            menuData.forEach(item => {
              this.buildItem(item.title, item.ref, item.icon);

                if (item.hasOwnProperty("submenu"))
                {
                  item.submenu.forEach(subitem => {
                    this.buildItem(subitem.title, subitem.ref, subitem.icon);
                  });
                }

            })
          }

        </div>
      );
  };
}

export default SidebarMenu;
```

Another solution would be:

```
  render() {

      return (
        <div>
          {
            menuData.forEach(function (item) {
              this.buildItem(item.title, item.ref, item.icon);

                if (item.hasOwnProperty("submenu"))
                {
                  item.submenu.forEach(function (subitem) {
                    this.buildItem(subitem.title, subitem.ref, subitem.icon);
                  }.bind(this));
                }

            }.bind(this))
          }

        </div>
      );
  };
}
```

But, IMO, the best solution would be to refactor the code using a component:

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';

const menuData = require('./data/admin.menu.json');

function MenuItem({key, ref, title, icon, submenu}) {
  return (
    <div className={`item${key}`}>
      <a href={ref}>{title}<i className={`fa ${icon}`}/></a>
      if (submenu) {
        submenu.map((subitem) => <MenuItem {...subitem} />)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

MenuItem.propTypes = {
    key: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    ref: PropTypes.string,
    icon: PropTypes.string,
    submenu: PropTypes.array,
};

class SidebarMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expanded: true,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    menuData.map((subitem) => <MenuItem {...subitem} />)
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SidebarMenu;
```

Comment: Why did you define `MenuItem` as `function MenuItem({key, ref, title, icon, submenu})` and not as another component `class MenuItem extends React.Component` ?

Comment: Because it does not need any state, nor any of the React component lifecycle methods. So I keep it simple.

Comment: @Mendes, there are 4 ways to define react components:  https://www.peterbe.com/plog/4-different-kinds-of-react-component-styles

Comment: It is rather old, check [this post](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.wynuubkjs) for why and how to use them. Maybe you should check also [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), Arrow functions (see the other answer for the link), and [named imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Answer (score 6):

The `this` referenced when you try to call `this.buildItem()` refers to the anonymous function's context, not your React component.

By using [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of functions defined using the `function` keyword inside the `render()` method, you can use `this` to reference the React component and its methods as desired.

Alternatively, you can use `(function () { ... }).bind(this)` to achieve the same result. But this is more tedious and the use of arrow functions is preferred.

Comment: Where the arrow function should be put ? Move `buildItem` inside `render()` and defined as `buildItem =>` ? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Mendes An arrow function can be used in place of any anonymous function. You would use arrow functions in place of the anonymous functions currently in your `render()` method. Furthermore, if you read the link on arrow functions I posted above, you'll see that arrow functions are always anonymous, so trying to define your `buildItem()` method with an arrow function wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line:

```
render() {
    let that = this
    return (
```

and then instead of `this.buildItem` use `that.buildItem` or you may need `that.buildItem.bind(that)`